# What's the most efficient way to combine objects in a List?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, java-stream

Let's say I have the following list.

```
List<StringInteger> test = new ArrayList<>(); //StringInteger is just a pojo with String and int
test.add(new StringInteger("a", 1));
test.add(new StringInteger("b", 1));
test.add(new StringInteger("a", 3));
test.add(new StringInteger("c", 1));
test.add(new StringInteger("a", 1));
test.add(new StringInteger("c", -1));

System.out.println(test); // [{ a : 1 }, { b : 1 }, { a : 3 }, { c : 1 }, { a : 1 }, { c : -1 }]
```

I need to write a method that would unite items by String key and add integers. So that the result list would be `[{ a : 5 }, { b : 1 }, { c : 0 }]`

I could do it using `HashMap`, but if I go that way - I'll have to create a `Map`, then use enhanced `for`-loop with `if(containsKey(...))` and then convert it back to List. It just seems like an overkill.

Is there a more elegant solution? I thought that `flatMap` from Stream API should do the thing, but I cannot figure out how.

Here's my clumsy solution. It works, but I believe that it can be done more simple than that.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (StringInteger stringInteger : test) {
    if (map.containsKey(stringInteger.getKey())) {
        int previousValue = map.get(stringInteger.getKey());
        map.put(stringInteger.getKey(), previousValue + stringInteger.getValue());
    } else {
        map.put(stringInteger.getKey(), stringInteger.getValue());
    }
}

List<StringInteger> result = map.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(stringIntegerEntry -> new StringInteger(stringIntegerEntry.getKey(), stringIntegerEntry.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(result); // [{ a : 5 }, { b : 1 }, { c : 0 }]
```

Comment: Using a `Map` is not overkill for this problem; it's what you're going to need to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @LouisWasserman said in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73325076/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-combine-objects-in-a-list#comment129492471_73325076), `HashMap` is the right tool for this task.

To translate the whole code into a stream, you can use the built-in *collector* [`groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) in conjunction with [`summingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summarizingInt(java.util.function.ToIntFunction)) as the downstream collector grouping.

```
result = test.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(   // creates an intermediate map Map<String, Integer>
        StringInteger::getKey,                         // mapping a key
        Collectors.summingInt(StringInteger::getValue) // generating a value
    ))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .map(entry -> new StringInteger(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
    .toList();
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to accomplish this is likely

```
List<StringInteger> combined = test.stream()
  .collect(
     Collectors.groupingBy(
        StringInteger::getKey,
        Collectors.summingInt(StringInteger::getValue)))
  .entrySet()
  .stream()
  .map(entry -> new StringInteger(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
  .toList();
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a full example with code based on the code seen in two good Answers [by Ivanchenko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73325374/642706) and [by Wasserman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73325372/642706).

Here, we use a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395) in Java 16+ to define your `StringInt` class.

The name `StringInt` is used rather than `StringInteger`, to stress that we have a primitive `int` as the member field type rather than `Integer` class as the type.

I should think a `Map < String , Integer >` would suffice for your goal.

```java
record StringInt( String string , int integer ) { }

List < StringInt > inputs =
        List.of(
                new StringInt( "a" , 1 ) ,
                new StringInt( "b" , 1 ) ,
                new StringInt( "a" , 3 ) ,
                new StringInt( "c" , 1 ) ,
                new StringInt( "a" , 1 ) ,
                new StringInt( "c" , - 1 )
        );

Map < String, Integer > results =
        inputs
                .stream()
                .collect(
                        Collectors.groupingBy(
                                StringInt :: string ,                          // Key
                                Collectors.summingInt( StringInt :: integer )  // Value
                        ) );
```

> results = {a=5, b=1, c=0}

Or, if you insist on instantiating `StringInt` objects as the result:

```java
record StringInt( String string , int integer ) { }

List < StringInt > inputs =
        List.of(
                new StringInt( "a" , 1 ) ,
                new StringInt( "b" , 1 ) ,
                new StringInt( "a" , 3 ) ,
                new StringInt( "c" , 1 ) ,
                new StringInt( "a" , 1 ) ,
                new StringInt( "c" , - 1 )
        );

List < StringInt > results =
        inputs
                .stream()
                .collect(
                        Collectors.groupingBy(
                                StringInt :: string ,                          // Key
                                Collectors.summingInt( StringInt :: integer )  // Value
                        ) )
                .entrySet()                                                    // Returns a Set < Entry < String , Integer > >
                .stream()
                .map( 
                    entry -> new StringInt( entry.getKey() , entry.getValue() ) 
                )
                .toList();
```

Comment: When there's no issue with type inference, good practice is to avoid explicit types with lambda arguments.  If you feel like it might be not obvious what would be the type of the stream element, it's better to simplify the stream extracting the part that generates a map into a separate method rather than providing explicit types which doesn't reduce complexity (in case if you not agree with this editing, please rollback).

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko I had indeed gone out of my way to insert the explicit type of the lambda argument because the type is not immediately obvious, especially for a student learning streams and lambdas. But in this case I’ll yield to your judgement. And I can see how the context with its `getKey` and `getValue` methods might suffice.

Answer (score 2):

> Here's my clumsy solution. It works, but I believe that it can be done more simple than that.

Just to show you, you can do the adding up in the map more neatly, without using streams:

```
for (StringInteger stringInteger : test) {
    map.merge(stringInteger.getKey(), stringInteger.getValue(), Integer::sum);
}
```